# GOPL: Binary assignment operator "saves us from re-evaluation?"

Tags: go

Page 36 of the *Go Programming Language* (GOPL) contains the following:

> Each of the arithmetic and bitwise binary operators has a corresponding *assignment operator* allowing, for example, the last statement to be rewritten as
>
> `count[x] *= scale`
>
> which saves us from having to repeat (and re-evaluate) the expression for the variable.

I do not understand the part about re-evaluation.  Do the authors mean to say that

```
count[x] = count[x] * scale
```

and

```
count[x] *= scale
```

compile to different bytecode?

Comment: "Do ... compile to different bytecode?" Maybe. Maybe not. But think if `count[n(17)]` with `func n(int) int`. With the assignment operator you have the guarantee that it is not evaluated twice. (And no: Nothing in Go compiles to bytecode. Go compiles to machine code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two versions may be **functionally different** (thank you for the hint, Volker):

```
package main

import "fmt"

var idx int
func n() int {
    idx++
    return idx - 1
}

func main() {
    var nums = [2](int){ 1, 2 }
    var adj = 10

    if true {
        nums[ n() ] += adj                   // Prints [11 2]
    } else {
        nums[ n() ] = nums[ n() ] + adj      // Prints [12 2]
    }

    fmt.Println("%v", nums)
}
```

(You can play with it [here](https://play.golang.org/p/LP3dTv_kDc).)

An equivalent C program behaves in exactly the same way.

The fact that this was surprising to me is itself surprising:  I seldom call functions to get an array index directly, so the thought never crossed my mind.